# Are these 4 accessibility&productivity related desktop feature available on macOS Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut, application-switcher

I switched from Linux to macOS Sierra not long ago.

There are some handier features of KDE plasma over macOS. I want to know if there are alternatives for macOS. ( Better free if available )

1. mouse scroll + command/option/controll/fn => tune transparency of window on focus.
2. mouse drag (inside window, instead of on title bar ) + command/option/controll/fn => drag window
3. task switcher. I installed HyperSwitch. It satisfied me with hiding inactive programs, but it can't show one entry for a task.
4. Press only right shift to switch input source

Comment: I wish. (Especially for the transparency.) There might be some third-party apps that could do _some_ of these things, possibly using the Accessibility API. You probably can't do the right-shift input source switch, though, because OS X doesn't generally do modifier-only shortcuts. Also, what do you mean by "one entry for a task"?

Comment: @seaturtle By "One entry for a task", I mean, NO two entry BUT one entry for applications that opened two windows. Just as the original task switcher does. However, the original task switcher keeps the entry for Hidden applications, which makes the switcher a mess.

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Maybe you could find an open-source one and modify it.

Comment: Found something for the window drag -- [Easy Move+Resize](https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize). Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: @seaturtle Thanks! It works bad though. I'll try modify it.

Comment: @seaturtle In fact, the latest update of my input source "Sogou Pinyin", proved a sole right Shift able to toggle English and Chinese. I don't know how, but it could.

Comment: Interesting, @DonaldWu. I didn't know that was possible!